# Improper Sorting using CAST in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have used this as an example to show the improper result that I am getting using `CAST`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ints VARCHAR(11));

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('100A'), 
('100B'), 
('101'), 
('102'), 
('101A'), 
('101B'), 
('101C'), 
('101D'), 
('100C'), 
('100D'), 
('101B');

SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY CAST(ints AS SIGNED)
```

[***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54570/1)

The Result should be

```
100A
100B
100C
100D
101
101A
101B
101C
101D
102
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 SELECT *
 FROM tbl
 ORDER BY CAST(ints AS char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, use

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY CAST(ints AS SIGNED), ints
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY CAST(`ints ` AS SIGNED)
```

for reverse order

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY CAST(`ints ` AS SIGNED) DESC
```